# C Parameter Array Declarators

Tags: c, arrays, function, syntax, parameters

In C99 there are variable-length arrays, and there can be static qualifiers (and type qualifiers) in parameter array declarators:

```
void f(int i, int *a);
void f(int i, int a[]);
void f(int i, int a[i]);
void f(int i, int a[*]);         // Only allowed in function prototypes.
void f(int i, int a[static i]);
```

Since array function parameters simply decay to pointers, is there any practical difference between the previous declarations, or is it a matter of style? When should any of them be used? In particular, what does the `static` qualifier imply? The standard does not render well clear the reason for each syntax.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as you are working with single-dimensional arrays only, the above declarations are all equivalent. The last one though

```
void f(int i, int a[static i])
```

has an extra effect. It is equivalent to the previous ones in terms of the parameter types, but also tells the compiler that it can rely on `a` parameter pointing to an array of at least `i` elements (which can be used in optimizations).

You are also forgetting another new declaration

```
void f(int i, int a[const])
```

This one actually does have an effect even in case of a single-dimensional array. It is equivalent to

```
void f(int i, int *const a)
```

although some might argue that const-qualifications on function parameters are useless. Before it was impossible to const-qualify the pointer the array parameter "decays" to when using the `[]` syntax for the declaration.

The `*` (as well as `i`) between the `[]` begins to matter only when it is used between the second (or greater) pair of `[]` in multi-dimensional array declaration. In essence, it is just like it has always been: array size in the parameter declaration always mattered only between the second or further pair of `[]`. The `*` is used in prototype declarations for VLA parameters, when the size value is not named explicitly. For example, you can declare

```
void bar(int n, int m, int a[n][m]);
```

and the compiler will know that `a` is a VLA since the sizes are not constants. But if you prefer not to name parameters in prototypes, how are you going to tell the compiler that `a` is a VLA? That's when `*` helps

```
void bar(int, int, int a[*][*]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I suspected at first that the `static` qualifier was related to optimization issues. Also, you forgot to mention that any type qualifiers can be declared in the array declarator, and these may play a much important role (such as `restrict` or `volatile`) than `const` itself.

Comment: If I do `func(int a[static 4][6])` the static can only be declared within the first brackets. What if I do this `func(int (*a)[static 6])` what will this do? Allow me to prefetch the first 6 values of the first row? And finally what about `func(int *a[static 6])`?

Comment: What would be the meaning of `void func1(int a[-1])`, `void func2(int a[some_global++]);`, or `void func3(int length, int dat[length]);`?

Comment: @supercat: `void func1(int a[-1])` is illegal. Negative array size is illegal in all contexts. `void func2(int a[some_global++]);` is replaced with `void func2(int a[*]);` and is equivalent to `void func2(int *a)` in a *function prototype* specifically. In a function *definition* this will declare `a` as VLA of corresponding size and *will* increment `some_global` each time the function is called.

Comment: @AnT: In a function definition, `foo(int length, int x[length])`, the type of `x` is not a VLA, but rather `int*`; does the standard say that a compiler must generate the array type and then ignore it, or ignore it from the get-go?  I would expect that pre-C99, invoking the above function with `length` equal to zero would have worked just fine, since the compiler would ignore the dimension, but have no idea whether that would be required for a C99 compiler.

Comment: @supercat: Well, it is a good question, for which I don't immediately see an answer in the language spec. GCC will increment `some_global` in response to each call to `void func2(int a[some_global++]) {}`, which means that GCC still "remembers" that parameter was declared as VLA even though the parameter type is adjusted to a plain `int *`.

Comment: @user10607: `static` is only allowed in the first `[]` of parameter declaration of array type, per 6.7.5.2/1. `func(int (*a)[static 6])` is simply illegal since `a` is not of array type. And I don't see anything "unusual" about `func(int *a[static 6])`, i.e. I don't understand what you are asking about in this last case.

Comment: @AnT: Making VLAs be types seems like a rather curious extension to the language, since it means that things like `typedef` become executable statements.  Personally, I wish C had simply defined non-broken `stalloc` and `stfree` methods which worked much like `malloc`, but specified that `stfree` would free the indicated object and everything `stalloc`'ed after it, that a routine which calls `stalloc` must call `stfree` before it returns, and that the state of anything `stalloc`'ed between a `setjmp` and `longjmp` will be indeterminate (meaning that if such things may exist...

Comment: ...code would need to call `stalloc` before the `setjmp`, and `stfree` that object afterward).  Such methods could allow many usage patterns that VLAs don't and could be implemented by *any* platform (using a wrapper around malloc if nothing else), even those incapable of supporting alloca or VLAs.  Probably too late now, though...