# Passing string to a function in C - with or without pointers?

Tags: c, string, function

When I'm passing a string to the function sometimes I use

```
char *functionname(char *name[256])
```

and sometimes I use it without pointers (for example:

```
char functionname(char name[256])
```

My question is,when do I need to use pointers ? Often I write programs without pointers and it works,but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean with "sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt"?

Comment: Please don't make us guess. Show your code. Enough for us to understand the problem.

Comment: For the first alternative, the argument is an array of 256 strings. At least if you fix the identifier error (no space in names)

Comment: No, as it is the first example is a syntax error: there is an extra identifier.

Comment: Here a good example on how to do different things with strings and  pointers in C
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46344713/5842403

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The accepted convention of passing C-strings to functions is to use a pointer:

```
void function(char* name)
```

When the function modifies the string you should also pass in the length:

```
void function(char* name, size_t name_length)
```

Your first example:

```
char *functionname(char *name[256])
```

passes an array of pointers to strings which is not what you need at all.

Your second example:

```
char functionname(char name[256])
```

passes an array of chars. The size of the array here doesn't matter and the parameter will decay to a pointer anyway, so this is equivalent to:

```
char functionname(char *name)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693429/c-parameter-array-declarators) for more details on array arguments in C.

Comment: Is there any harm if the function receives the string the way : char functionname(char string[256])

Comment: `void function(char* name)` is thus only applicable when it does not modify the C-string? Wouldn't it make sense to declare it `const`? As for most, you're sending a pointer that should also be const, since you won't be changing the pointer itself?

Comment: `char *functionname(char *string name[256])` is a syntax error,  not "passes an array of pointers".

Comment: where is the string actually stored?
if we just do `functionname("this is a string")` where will the string be stored?
are we sure it will not overwrite anything as we didn't give a length to the space we want to allocate.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you meant to write

```
char *functionname(char *string[256])
```

Here you are declaring a function that takes an array of 256 pointers to `char` as argument and returns a pointer to char. Here, on the other hand,

```
char functionname(char string[256])
```

You are declaring a function that takes an array of 256 `char`s as argument and returns a `char`.

In other words the first function takes an array of strings and returns a string, while the second takes a string and returns a character.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a pointer. It points to the start of a sequence of "objects".

If we do this: `ìnt arr[10];`, then `arr` is a pointer to a memory location, from which ten integers follow. They are uninitialised, but the memory is allocated. It is exactly the same as doing `int *arr = new int[10];`.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void StringSort(char S[5][30]);
void main()
{
 char S[5][30];
 int i;

 printf("Unesi 5 stringova:\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  gets(S[i]);

 printf("\nUneseni stringovi su:\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  puts(S[i]);

 StringSort(S);

 printf("\nStringovi sortirani po broju znakova su:\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  puts(S[i]);
}

void StringSort(char S[5][30])
{
 char pS[30];
 int i, j;

 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  for(j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
   if(strlen(S[i]) > strlen(S[j]))
   {
    strcpy(pS, S[i]);
    strcpy(S[i], S[j]);
    strcpy(S[j], pS);
   }

Comment: An array is *not* a pointer. for example, `sizeof(arr)` is different for an array and a pointer. And `new` is C++, not C.

Comment: @interjay, sorry. Didn't think about that. You can of course use malloc() instead.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char *fn(char *s1,char *s2);

int main()
{
char a1[20],a2[20];
printf("Unesi string:");
gets(a1);
printf("Unesi drugi string:");
gets(a2);

printf("Prvi po abecednom redu je %s",fn(a1,a2));

}

char *fn(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    if(strcmp(s1,s2)<0) return s1;
    else return s2;
}

Comment: BOTH OF THESE PROGRAMS WORK BUT IN ONE I DIDN'T USE POINTERS AND IN OTHER I DID.

LOOK AT THE LINKS

http://tny.cz/809ae075

http://tny.cz/60dc68cf

Comment: An array is not a pointer. An array VARIABLE is a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: An array is not a pointer. In most cases, array names are just converted to pointers. Refer this link to know more about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer