# How to pass the entire char array with its values to another function?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, prototype

I'm working on how to pass the entire char array including its values to another function. here's the code:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 100
void Prefix_Conversion(char Infix_Postfix_Expression[STACK_SIZE]); 

int main(){
    //some process code here
    Prefix_Conversion(Infix_Postfix_Expression[STACK_SIZE]);
}

void Prefix_Conversion(char Infix_Postfix_Expression[]){
    //some code here
}
```

It gives me an error of:

**[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [f-permissive]
[Note] initilizing argument of 1 if 'void Prefix_Conversion(char*)'**

Is the prototype, arguments and array right?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131863/passing-string-to-a-function-in-c-with-or-without-pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Prefix_Conversion(Infix_Postfix_Expression[STACK_SIZE]);` you're passing one character to a function that needs `char *`, hence the error message.

Simply pass
`Prefix_Conversion(Infix_Postfix_Expression);`

Comment: ...and that access is out of bound also. :)