# Function parameter as array with declared size

Tags: c, parameters

I frequently use the following convention to inform client code that a function requires an argument of an array with defined size:

```
/* File foo.h */
int foo (int arg[10]);
```

The message I want to give to client code is that they **must** provide an array of type `int` with 10 positions.

I am aware that it is not very usual, so I came here to ask: Am I missing any side effect of this convention ? Is it anyhow harmful?

Thank!

Comment: Why not use `int foo (int arg[/*10*/]);`? Commenting the dimension

Comment: Why not use `int foo (int *arg, int elements)`;?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Parameter Array Declarators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693429/c-parameter-array-declarators)

Comment: @WeatherVane It's intended for humans, as a way to let them know that the array should always have 10 elements.

Comment: You can wrap the array to a struct and pass a pointer to that struct in. Arrays in structs have size info.

Comment: @user3528438 Would you tell me more about the difference between the two ?

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking it could be enforced by error checking at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insist on getting an array of size 10, you can use:

```
int foo (int (*arg)[10]);
```

The ill-side effects of this are:

1. In the function, you have to use:

   ```
   (*arg)[index]
   ```

   instead of just

   ```
   arg[index]
   ```
2. The calling function must use:

   ```
   int array[10];
   foo(&array);
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   int array[10];
   foo(array);
   ```
3. You cannot use an array that has more than 10 elements.

   ```
   int array[20];
   foo(&array);   // Not OK.
   ```
4. You cannot use a `malloc`ed array.

   ```
   int* array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
   foo(array);   // Not OK.
   ```

Now pick the solution that is least harmful.

Comment: At least, it's safe to cast the pointer to the array if it's too big or allocated: for 3. : `foo((void *)array)` or `foo((int(*)[])array)`; for 4.: `foo((int(*)[])array)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct arrayContainerTen{
  int data[10];
}
void aFunction(struct arrayContainerTen *pAnArray)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(pAnArray->data);
}
main()
{
     arrayContainerTen anArray;
     aFunction(&anArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in writing it like this. But just be aware that the compiler will not enforce the requirement. A declaration like that is treated by the compiler as if you'd written.

```
int foo(int *arg);
```