# X,Y passing size for the array in C function

Tags: c, function

I've declared my function where I want to find the minimum from diagonals [0][0] ... [5][5] and [0][5]... [5][0].
I have the algorithm but my problem is with the actual function header.

I have problem with creating the formal arguments for the function.
I know that we have to pass at least `x[][this]` size of array to the function, but I tried various combinations, even

```
double minimum(int size, double x[][size]){...}

double minimum(double x[][int size]){...}
```

The first case gives an error when calling:

```
minimum(10, x[][10])
error: expected expression before ']' token `
```

The second case gives an error in declaration of function:

```
error: expected expression before 'int'
```

Can someone tell what the problem is (or problems are)?

Comment: The first function prototype is correct, but the way you call the function `minimum(10, x[][10])` is not syntactically correct. Can you provide more context? Like a self-contained small program.

Comment: The first function prototype should work with C99. When you call the function, just pass `x` where `x` is an array that you have defined as `int x[10][10]`. (The number of rows may vary, but the number of columns must be cosistent with the `size` you pass.)

Comment: @MarošČergeť: Please don't post long code fragments as comments; edit and update your question instead.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I realised it then when I posted it. This is my very first post here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double minimum(int rowsize,int size, double x[rowsize][size]){...}` 
or simply

`double minimum(int rowsize,int size, double x[][size]){...}`

So specifying `rowsize` is optional.

But here I guess it is square `size x size` so it will be

`double minimum(int size, double x[][size]){...}`

So you are correct in that.

### How to call it?

`minimum(10,x)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with an array of the fixed size 5 then you can declare the function like

```
double minimum( double x[][5] );
```

and call it like

```
minimum( x );
```

If the size of the array can be changed you can use variable length arrays and declare the function like

```
double minimum( size_t n, double x[][n] );
```

of for self-documentation like

```
double minimum( size_t n, double x[n][n] );
```

The function can be called like

```
minimum( 10, x );
```

or like

```
minimum( sizeof( x ) / sizeof( *x ), x );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a previous formal argument as the dimension for  a later formal argument of a C99 function, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693432/841108) question.

So the following code is valid:

```
double
sum (int w, int l, double mat[w][l])
{
  double s = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
      s += mat[i][j];
  return s;
}
```

If you have declared

```
double t[5][7];
```

You can call

```
double s = sum(5,7,t);
```

However, you might not want that. A possibility could be to represent a matrix ([abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)) as a pointer to a `struct` ending with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
struct matrix_st {
  unsigned w;
  unsigned h;
  double m[];  // conventionally w*h double numbers
};
```

You could allocate it with

```
struct matrix_st *make_matrix (unsigned w, unsigned h)
{
  // we might check that w and h are of reasonable size....
  // to avoid arithmetic overflow, or excessive memory allocation.
  struct matrix_st* pm = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix_st) + sizeof(double)*w*h);
  if (!pm) return NULL; // malloc failure
  pm->w = w;
  pm->h = h;
  for (long i=w*h-1; i>=0; i--) pm->m[i] = 0.0;
  return pm;
};
```

for example

```
 struct matrix_st* mat = make_matrix(5,7);
```

and when you are finished, just call `free(mat);` (preferably followed by `mat = NULL;`).

You could code the function accessing it as:

```
inline double matrix_access(struct matrix_st*pm, unsigned i, unsigned j)
{
   assert (pm != NULL);
   assert (i < pm->w);
   assert (j < pm->h);
   return pm->m[i*pm->w+j];
}
```

<sup>(practically speaking, since that function is `inline`, it can run really fast, nearly as fast as other solutions or answers to your question)</sup>

I leave to the reader the exercise of coding other matrix functions (including modification of an element of the matrix, the equivalent of `sum`, etc...).

Comment: `w * h * sizeof(double)` --> `sizeof(double) * w * h` would help guard against unwelcome overflow (or `unsigned` wraparound, rather) by forcing `size_t` arithmetic.