# How to use pointer to multi dimentional array in C language?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, pointer-to-array

I have 2-D array

```
char arr[2][3]={"sam","ali"}
```

and pointer to this array

```
char(*ptr)[3]=arr;
```

How can I use this pointer to print `arr[2][2]` which in this case is `i`.
I've tried `* (*(ptr+1)+2)` the same way I am dealing with the array but didn't work so can any one help and tell me how to deal with pointer to array in this case to print element `[2][2]`.

Comment: Avoid multi-dimensional arrays in C. Consider using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to implement your own matrix abstract data type, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108)

Comment: Be careful when using strings and fixed-sized arrays, you have to remember that a string of three characters really need space for *four* characters, to include the terminating null character `'\0'`.

Comment: Note that `"sam"` actually requires 4 bytes, as it includes the string termination character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
char(*ptr)[3]=arr;
```

isn't a *pointer to a multi dimensional array*, it's a *pointer to one-dimensional array of size `3`*. But that's fine because a pointer can always also point to an *array* of the type it points to. So you have `ptr` point to an array of *one-dimensional arrays of size `3`*. So far just for clarifying the terms.

Your immediate problem are just wrong indices. Indices are based on `0`, not `1`, so with

```
char arr[2][3]={"sam","ali"}
```

valid indices for the first dimension of `arr` are just `0` and `1`. The element you're looking for would be at `ptr[1][2]`.

---

With the *pointer arithmetics notation* in your question, you actually had the indices right, so I can't see where your problem was in **this** case. The following prints `i` as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[2][3]={"sam","ali"};
    char(*ptr)[3]=arr;
    printf("%c\n", *(*(ptr+1)+2));
}
```

Note this is completely equivalent to the more readable `ptr[1][2]`.

---

*Side note:* if you expected your elements to be *strings* -- they aren't, see [haccks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707002/2371524) for the explanation (a string must end with a `'\0'`, your string literals do, but your array needs the room to hold it).

Answer (score 8):

You should not print `arr[2][2]` because you are accessing array out of bounds. Also note that there is no space for `'\0'` character to be stored in in the given array.

```
char arr[2][4] = {"sam","ali"}  
char(*ptr)[4] = arr;
```

Using `ptr` you can access the elements of `arr` as `ptr[1][2]`.