# Why is this matrix or array, is just storing garbage?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

```
#include    <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int row, col, mat[row][col], i, j, high = 0, sec_high = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
        printf("\nEnter %d row %d col.\n", i, j);
    scanf("%d", &mat[row][col]);
    printf("%d \n", mat[row][col]);
        }
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
            if (high < mat[i][j]){
                sec_high = high;
                high = mat[i][j];                               
            }
            else if(sec_high < mat[i][j]){
                    sec_high = mat[i][j];
        }
        printf("i%d j%d h%d s%d mat%d\n", i, j, high, sec_high, mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The  second highest number is: %d.", sec_high); 
    
}
```

What I am trying to do over here is simply to take out the second highest number from a matrix. Every thing is fine until The 3rd `printf` come where I am getting random numbers huge numbers. Which is totally unexpected since I have already printed those numbers once while inputting and every thing was fine. So what is the logical error over here?

Comment: You use `row` and `col` before you initialize or read anything into them. `int row, col, mat[row][col]`

Comment: Read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function you are using (e.g. `scanf`, `printf`, etc...). Compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use `gdb` to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108) is relevant to your question

Comment: C programs are executed from the top to bottom. Not all lines at once.

Comment: What is the difference between assigning to a variable and reading into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int row, col, mat[row][col], i, j, high = 0, sec_high = 0;
```

is wrong, since `row` and `col` are not initialized. They could contain arbitrary values. What would happen if `row` contained 0x1fff0123 and `col` contained 0x34567890 ?

```
scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
```

is also wrong, since [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail and you don't test that.

At last, allocating large matrixes as [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is poor taste. Since the call stack is *very* limited (e.g. to a megabyte, and that means about 250 000 `int`-s, which is not much, since `sizeof(int)` is usually four bytes)

I recommend allocating your matrixes in the heap, using [C dynamic memory allocation](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108). Be sure to test success of [`malloc` or of `calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) and don't forget to call `free` later. Consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.oirg/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

If you use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings enabled, e.g. as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, you would get useful warnings. Then you can use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Once your code is correct and you want to benchmark it, enable optimizations by adding the `-O2` compiler flag.

Be sure to **read more about C** (e.g. the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) reference) **and the documentation of your C compiler and your debugger**. You might be later interested by the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and by static analyzers for C code such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (or by [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) draft report).

### Take inspiration from *existing* open source C code

e.g. on [github](https://github.com/). Or [GNU software](https://www.gnu.org/software/) (e.g. [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) or [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) etc...) or interpreters or runtime components in [Python](https://python.org/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/), or simple C compilers such as [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) or [tinycc](https://bellard.org/tcc/) (both of these are coded in C mostly) or libraries like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/) and many others.

Consider using the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code.

Comment: What is the best way to take input in a multi dimensional array, can you provide an example?

Comment: Why would there be a single best way? Regarding examples, look on [github](http://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)