# Pointers, function and 2d array in c program

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

i try make a program to show the largest number in column a 2d array, but this program have a problem
which cannot produce the desired result. in my compiler says :

```
 3  5   [Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[(sizetype)(b)]'
```

and this my code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    int array2d(int *x, int a, int b){
        int i,j;
        int max[j];
        for(i=0; i<a ; i++){
            max[j]= *x;
            for(j=0; j<b ; j++){
                if(*x>max[j])
                {
                    max[j]=*x;
                }
            }
            printf("\nthe maximum value of each column is : %d", max[j]);
        
    }
    int main(){
        int a,b,i,j;
        
        printf("enter the size of array (rows) & (column) : ");
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        
        int x[a][b];
        
        printf("enter the number : ");
        for ( i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        array2d(x,a,b);
        
        return 0;
    }
```

the program input :

```
4 4
```

and input number :

```
1 3 2 1
8 4 3 2
1 2 3 4
9 8 7 6
```

And expected this output :

```
9 8 7 6
```

What should I do to fix it? I need your opinion and maybe anyone wants to help me to write the right code.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108) to a related question

Comment: i still don't understand it after reading it @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Then you need to read a good book on C programming, such as  [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Once you have read that book, refer to [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and read some C draft standard such as [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) to understand the behavior of your program. You could use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to edit your source code. StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework service

Comment: Take also inspiration from *existing* open source programs on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

See the pointer arithmetics.

```
void printArray(int *x, size_t a, size_t b)
{
    if(x && a && b)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < b; j++)
                printf("%d\t", *(x + i * a + j));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void array2d(int *x, size_t a, size_t b)
{
    if(x && a && b)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            int max = *(x + i);
            for(size_t j = 0; j < a; j++)
            {
                if(*(x + j * a + i) > max)
                {
                    max = *(x + j * a + i);
                }
            }
            printf("\nthe maximum value of each column is : %d", max);
        }
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    size_t a = 0,b = 0;
    
    printf("enter the size of array (rows) & (column) : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("\n");
    

    int x[a][b];

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            x[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    }
    
    printArray(*x, a, b);
    array2d(*x, a, b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zzaxG6

Comment: thank you but can you write in simple c code

Answer (score 2):

You declared a two-dimensional variable length array

```
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    
    int x[a][b];
```

The element type of the array is `int[b]`.

Used in expressions array designators with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this function call

```
array2d(x,a,b);
```

the array designator `x` is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[b]`. However the corresponding function parameter has the type `int *`.

```
int array2d(int *x, int a, int b){
```

and there is no implicit conversion from the type `int ( * )[b]` to the type `int *`. So the compiler issues an error.

Moreover within the function you are using another variable length array `max` the size of which is set with the uninitialized variable `j`.

```
    int i,j;
    int max[j];
```

There is no need to declare this array to output maximum values.

Also the function has the return type `int` but returns nothing.

So in any the function is incorrect and does not make a sense.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void array2d( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        int max = a[0][j];

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < m; i++ )
        {
            if ( max < a[i][j] ) max = a[i][j];
        }

        printf( "\nthe maximum value in the column %zu is: %d", j, max );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void array2d( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        int max = a[0][j];

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < m; i++ )
        {
            if ( max < a[i][j] ) max = a[i][j];
        }

        printf( "\nthe maximum value in the column %zu n is: %d", j, max );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t m, n;
    
    printf( "enter the size of array (rows) & (column) : " );
    scanf( "%zu %zu", &m, &n );
    int a[m][n];

    
    printf( "enter the number : " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            scanf( "%d", &a[i][j] );
        }
    }
    
    array2d( m, n, a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
enter the size of array (rows) & (column) : 4 4
enter the number : 
1 3 2 1
8 4 3 2
1 2 3 4
9 8 7 6
the maximum value in the column 0 is: 9
the maximum value in the column 1 is: 8
the maximum value in the column 2 is: 7
the maximum value in the column 3 is: 6
```

If in the loops of the function to use pointers then the function can look the following way

```
void array2d( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] )
{
    for ( int *p = *a; p != *a + n; ++p )
    {
        int max = *p;

        for ( int ( *q )[m] = a + 1; q != a + m; ++q )
        {
            if ( max < **q ) max = *( *q + ( p - *a ) );
        }

        printf( "\nthe maximum value in the column %zu is: %d", ( size_t )( p - *a ), max );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but  i look for a using pointers

Answer (score 0):

In your code,when you declare a matrix a = rows, b = cols and you use the while loop to make this condtion: "rows>0 or cols>0"(ignored the 0 and negative numbers)

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Function declaration to input and print two dimensional array
  void input_Matrix(int cols ,int matrix[][cols],int rows);
  void output_Matrix(int cols ,int matrix[][cols],int rows);
//Function to know the maximum of each column
  void Max_Cols(int cols ,int matrix[][cols],int rows);

int main()
{
     int rows,cols;
     do
     {
         printf("Enter the size of rows of this Matrix : ");
         scanf("%d",&rows);
     }while(rows<1);
     do
     {
         printf("Enter the size of cols of this Matrix : ");
         scanf("%d",&cols);
     }while(cols<1||cols!=rows);
     int matrix[rows][cols];

     //Input elements in the matrix
     printf("\nEnter elements of [%d,%d] matrix \n",rows,cols);

     input_Matrix(cols,matrix,rows);
     //Print elements in the matrix

     printf("\nDisplay Elements of [%d,%d] matrix \n",rows,cols);
     output_Matrix(cols,matrix,rows);

     //Print the maximum of each cols
     printf("\n\nMaximum of each column :\n");
     Max_Cols(cols,matrix,rows);

     return 0;
}

/**
 * Function to display elements of two dimensional array (matrix)
 * on console.
 *
 * @matrix  2D array to display as input.
 * @rows    Total rows in 2D matrix.
 * @cols    Total columns in 2D matrix.
 */

 void input_Matrix(int cols ,int (*matrix)[cols],int rows)
 {
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      {
           for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
           {
                // (*(matrix + i) + j is equivalent to &matrix[i][j]
                scanf("%d", (*(matrix + i) + j));
           }
      }
 }


void output_Matrix(int cols ,int (*matrix)[cols],int rows)
{
      for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      { printf("\n");
           for (int j=0;j<cols;j++)
           {
               // *(*(matrix + i) + j) is equivalent to &matrix[i][j]
               printf("%d ", *(*(matrix + i) + j));
           }
      }
}

void Max_Cols(int cols ,int (*matrix)[cols],int rows)
{
      for (int j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {int *max=matrix[0][j];
           for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
           {
              // *(*(matrix + i) + j) is equivalent to &matrix[i][j]
              if(*(*(matrix + i) + j)>max)
              {
                   max=*(*(matrix + i) + j);
              }
           }
           printf("\nThe Maximum of column %d is : %d\n",j,max);
      }
}
```