# Matrix pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I will go straight to what I'm asking for, I also see some similar question but is not what I'm looking for...so it seems I have to ask with a new forum.
I'm preparing  myself for a future examination, where is not required the pointer, but I would like to get some extra information and abilities.
Here's the code followed by the question...
I'm using Fedora 33, I know is different from some IDE on Windows (ex: Visual Studio or Dev C++)

```
/* It's just a simple test, if this work I will get myself into a more complicated one, as you could read in the 
 * forum, I'm getting ready ( just a recheck of my abilities ) for an universitary examinaton. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5

void casual_generation(int** mat);
void prompt_print(int** mat);

int main()
{
    int **mat[N][N];
    casual_generation(**mat);
    prompt_print(**mat);
}

void casual_generation(int** mat)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 50;
}

void prompt_print(int** mat)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            printf("%d  ", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Somebody else on the forum used malloc, struct or other stuff, as you can see in this picture, when I try to execute him it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
[screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iceG.png)
Where is my error?
And if you want, can you also send me the version with the passed value pointer?
Thanks for whoever will give me an answer, and time dedicated.

Comment: you can remove all that few lines of story you added before question, and answer for your question _Segmentation fault (core dumped)" ,  Where is my error?_,  is pointers should not be used with out allocation of memory first, if you try to do so , the behavior is undefined.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108) very relevant to your question and read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). With GCC, compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use GDB. Once happy with your code, you might add `-O2`. Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to do

```
Int mat[N][N];
```

and

```
casual_generation(mat);
prompt_print(mat);
```

By passing `**mat` you are passing `mat[0][0]` that is an `int`, but you want to pass the whole matrix which is a pointer to pointers to int (i.e. `int **`)

And you may want to introduce `srand()` in your code.

Just to make things clear:

`mat` is of type `int **` and it's the whole matrix (or if you want it's a pointer to the first row)

`*mat` is of type `int *` and it's the first row of the matrix (or if you want it's a pointer to the first element of the first row)

`**mat` is of type `int` and it's the first element of the first row of the matrix

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
int **mat[N][N];
```

does not make a sense. It means that you have a matrix elements of which are pointers of the type `int **`. But you need a matrix elements of which are integer numbers of the type `int`. That is you need a declaration like this

```
int mat[N][N];
```

So now you have a two-dimensional array (or matrix) of integers.

As you are going to pass this two-dimensional array to functions then used as an argument expression it is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[N]`.

Correspondingly the functions that accepts such an array should be declared like

```
void casual_generation( int mat[][N], size_t n );
void prompt_print( int mat[][N], size_t n );
```

or (that is fully equivalent) like

```
void casual_generation( int ( * mat )[N], size_t n );
void prompt_print( int ( *mat )[N], size_t n );
```

because the compiler adjusts function parameters having array types to pointers to array element types.

Now for example the first function can be defined the following way

```
void casual_generation( int ( * mat )[N], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
casual_generation( mat, N );
```

A similar way can be defined the function `prompt_print`.

Using the second parameter makes the function more general. For example it can be called for two-dimensional arrays with different numbers of rows.

Now I will explain why you are getting a segmentation fault in your original code.

You have this declaration

```
int **mat[N][N];
```

a two dimensional array of pointers of the type `int **`.

Then you are using the expression `**mat` as an argument of function calls like this

```
casual_generation(**mat);
```

Then you are applying the dereference operator like `*mat` the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element (row) having the type `int ** ( * )[N]`. So dereferencing this pointer you get the first row of your array `int **[N]`. Applying the second time the dereferenced  operator to this expression that has an array type the used expression is again is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int **( * )`. That is it points to the first element of the first row of the original two-dimensional array. Dereferencing this pointer you get the first element of the type `int **`. This uninitialized pointer with indeterminate value the function accepts as its argument.

Thus dereferencing this first uninitialized element of the original matrix within the function

```
mat[i][j] = rand() % 50;
   ^^^
```

you get a segmentation fault. The reason of the fault is the incorrect matrix and the corresponding function parameter as it was shown above in tbe beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is my error?

The "Segmentation fault" error happens because you define the variable `mat` as a pointer, but don't allocate any memory for it to point to.

```
 int **mat[N][N];
```

Comment: It's rather defined as a 2d array of pointers to pointer to int

Answer (score 0):

```
int **mat[N][N];
```

Here, you defined a double pointer to a 2D array. You only need to use one of those - a double pointer *or* a 2D array, like so:

```
int mat[N][N];
```

However, the bigger problem comes from trying to interchange 2D arrays and double pointers. This [isn't possible in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1) since the 2D array is laid out flat in memory.
You need to create an array `mat_ptr` of pointers yourself and then pass that to `casual_generation` and `prompt_print`.

Finally, these `casual_generation` and `prompt_print` functions expect to be given a pointer, so you shouldn't dereference the pointer with `**` before calling the function.

The final working code is:

```
int main()
{
    int mat[N][N];
    int *mat_ptr[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        mat_ptr[i] = mat[i];

    casual_generation(mat_ptr);
    prompt_print(mat_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can find a detailed explanation why the code crashed in the other answer I will only propose a quite elegant solution that uses a neat though little known  feature from C99 called *Variable Length Arrays* (aka VLA).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void casual_generation(int n, int mat[n][n]);
void prompt_print(int n, int mat[n][n]);

int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    int mat[N][N];
    casual_generation(N, mat);
    prompt_print(N, mat);
}

void casual_generation(int n, int mat[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 50;
}

void prompt_print(int n, int mat[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d  ", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It compiles in pedantic mode with no warnings and it works like a charm.
VLA were introduced to C to simplify numerical computation over multidimensional arrays.