# Installing and using a shared library

Tags: c, gcc

I have a project I'm working on that currently has a `matrix.c` file containing a some functions and has a corresponding header `matrix.h`. I made a shared library `libccalc.so` using `matrix.c` and another file. I am trying to create a directory in `/usr/local/lib` and a directory in `/usr/local/include`, both called `ccalc` to house the respective `.so` and `.h` files which can then later be used to compile programs using the functionality of `libccalc.so`. However, when I do this I am getting an error.

To be precise, `matrix.c` contains functions: 
`Matrix *mat_create(int rows, int cols)`, 
`void mat_fill(Matrix *mat, double *entries)` and 
`void mat_print(Matrix *mat)` 
which are declared in `matrix.h`.  I place the files in their respective directories as explained above, I run `ldconfig /usr/local/lib/ccalc` and I make a new file `test.c` in some other directory with the following:

```
// test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {
    Matrix *m = mat_create(2, 2);
    double entries[4] = {1, 2, 3 ,4};
    mat_fill(m, entries);

    mat_print(m);

    return 0; 
}
```

`matrix.h` contains the following:

```
// matrix.h

#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#define MAX_SIZE 50

typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

struct Matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double *data;
};

Matrix *mat_create(int n, int p);
void mat_fill(Matrix *mat, double *entries);
void mat_print(Matrix *mat);

#endif
```

When I enter the command: `gcc -I/usr/local/include/ccalc -L/usr/local/lib/ccalc -lccalc test.c -o test`, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccesD44J.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `mat_create'
/usr/bin/ld: test.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `mat_fill'
/usr/bin/ld: test.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `mat_print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I place `libccalc.so` and `matrix.h` in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, enter `ldconfig` and enter the command `gcc -L/usr/local/lib/ccalc -lccalc test.c -o test`, and run `./test`, it works perfectly

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you include the contents of `matrix.h` if at all possible?

Comment: yup, just updated and added contents of `matrix.h`

Comment: It would be more conventional to put the header directly in `/usr/local/include` and the library directly in `/usr/local/lib` or possibly `/usr/local/lib64`.  If you instead put them in subdirectories of those then you will need to configure the dynamic linker with the correct library directory, and you will need to either tell the compiler which directory to search for the header, or else include the subdirectory in the `#include` directive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is this normal? in my `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` there is are directories for python3 stuff. I had read that `libm.so` is in `/usr/lib` but when I checked, I couldnt find it, just a bunch of directories, so I thought that is what people do

Comment: @CarsonJames, on most Unix-y systems, including most Linuxes, it is common to install libraries directly into .../lib or .../lib64, and to install headers directly into .../include, and if you do so then it is easier to find them at compile time *and* run time.  Python is a rather special case, and should not be regarded as a model.  libm and the rest of the C standard library, too -- we're talking about add-on C and C++ libraries, such as yours.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ah gotcha, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot. Please read the documentation about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Also, `test` is often a builtin command. See [test(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

So (on Linux) rename `test.c` as `prog.c` then compile your program with

```
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -g prog.c -L/usr/local/lib/ccalc -lccalc -o prog
```

Then use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the behavior of  `prog`, and [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) with [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) to analyze `prog`. See also [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

Regarding building shared libraries, read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf)

You probably want to compile `matrix.c` into `libcalc.so` using

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -O -shared -g matrix.c -o libcalc.so
```

but you might need other program arguments.

Regarding matrix operations, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108) could be inspirational.

Comment: thanks, I added `-I/usr/local/include/ccalc` to the command you gave me and it worked, so I think my problem was me not using the correct order